# "Routine" function before the call of a function in python

Tags: python, oop, pep8

World!

I'm creating a class in python called `FBST`.It has the following attributes:

```
class FBST:

    def __init__(self, x, verbose=False):

        self._rejected_met = []
        self._acceptance_met = []
        self._acceptance_bar = []
        self._rejected_bar = []
        self.x = x
        self.verbose = verbose
```

As you can see, it has 4 diferent lists. Those 4 lists store information about a function called `_chain()`. Each time I call the `chain()` method,  have to "clean" those 4 lists, turning each one of them in to a empty list again. I'm using the following code to make this cleaning process.

```
def chain(self):

    #cleaning the attributes
    for att in dir(self):
        if att.startswith("_"):
            setattr(self, att, [])
```

Is this there a more "pythonic" approach to this loop in the beggining of the function?

Comment: Perhaps you can refactor those attributes into a single dictionary? This allows you to iterate through the variables that need to be reset, instead of having to iterate through all attributes and use an if statement to identify if it needs clearing.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, no need for this if comparsion in the start of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than depending on a specific naming convention for the variables, put them in a dictionary.

```
class FBST:

    def __init__(self, x, verbose=False):
        self.acc_rej = {
            "rejected_met": [],
            "accepance_met": [],
            "rejected_bar": [],
            "acceptance_bar": []
        }
        self.x = x
        self.verbose = verbose

    def chain(self):
        for key in self.acc_rej:
            self.acc_rej[key] = []
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. thats a smart move, no need for that `startswith()` comparsion. I'll accepted that as the answer.